# Can't figure out why Ethernet packets are ignored

Tags: linux, debian, ethernet

I'm trying to setup an ethernet connection between a PC (Windows XP) and a notebook (Debian 9) using a crossover cable. No DHCP, just manually set IPs and a netmask. The notebook has Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 Fast Ethernet Controller.

If I run on the notebook a virtual machine with a bridged connection and try to connect it to the PC, all works fine. But the host system ignores incoming packets from `eth0` at all, regardless of those type (ARP, ICMP, TCP...). I can see all of the incoming packets in Wireshark with promisc mode enabled.

- It seems to be no firewalls enabled (ebtables, ufw)
- Network Manager service is disabled
- `iptables -L` has no rules
- Altering `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/arp_accept` does not help
- `ifconfig eth0` shows there are no dropped packets
- There are no other network interfaces besides `lo`

So how can I find out what does drop packages?

---

Configuration details

```
bodqhrohro@localhost:/data/text/lectures/sc$ sudo ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.0.5  netmask 255.240.0.0  broadcast 172.31.255.255
        inet6 fe80::de0e:a1ff:fede:2aa  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether dc:0e:a1:de:02:aa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 787  bytes 70998 (69.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 250  bytes 22898 (22.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 1  collisions 0

lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 454522  bytes 71984295 (68.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 454522  bytes 71984295 (68.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

bodqhrohro@localhost:/data/text/lectures/sc$ ip addr show
1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:0e:a1:de:02:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.0.5/12 brd 172.31.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::de0e:a1ff:fede:2aa/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlan0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:06:e6:a9:83:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
94: wwp0s18f0u5i1:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ba:41:f1:73:9c:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
bodqhrohro@localhost:/data/text/lectures/sc$ sudo brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
bodqhrohro@localhost:/data/text/lectures/sc$
```

And from the XP machine (in Russian though)

```
C:\Documents and Settings\UserXP>ipconfig /all

Настройка протокола IP для Windows

        Имя компьютера  . . . . . . . . . : XP
        Основной DNS-суффикс  . . . . . . :
        Тип узла. . . . . . . . . . . . . : неизвестный
        IP-маршрутизация включена . . . . : нет
        WINS-прокси включен . . . . . . . : да

Подключение по локальной сети 2 - Ethernet адаптер:

        DNS-суффикс этого подключения . . :
        Описание  . . . . . . . . . . . . : NVIDIA nForce Networking Controller
        Физический адрес. . . . . . . . . : 6C-F0-49-9D-C1-6D
        Dhcp включен. . . . . . . . . . . : нет
        IP-адрес  . . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.1
        Маска подсети . . . . . . . . . . : 255.240.0.0
        IP-адрес  . . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::6ef0:49ff:fe9d:c16d%4
        Основной шлюз . . . . . . . . . . :
        DNS-серверы . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                            fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                            fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
```

Comment: and `/sbin/ifconfig eth0` shows the interface as up?  Do the RX TX data counts change over time?

Comment: Yes, it's up and the counters grow both on incoming and outcoming ping attempts.

Comment: I did set up a connection in VM to make sure this is not a cable or network card issue. Configuration: http://pastebin.com/NB5hcujy

Comment: You might check your route via `ip route show`

Comment: @JeffSpaulding

`$ ip route show`

`172.16.0.0/12 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.0.5`

Comment: @roalma part of `ipconfig /all` on PC (sorry, it's in Russian): http://pastebin.com/nF5NUNcG

Comment: (Thank you for the network configuration.) When you say that « _`iptables -L` has no rules_ » the policy is `ACCEPT` for all three chains, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, for all of INPUT, FORWARD and OUTPUT.

Comment: does the host start accepting packets if you run `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0`?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro it's already zero for both `all` and `eth0`.